# Google-oauth:Not authorized to request the scopes

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, scribe, google-oauth-java-client

I implemented Google oauth1 in my web app and it was working fine some two months ago as i was busy with some other stuff, today i have to test the app but I got the following error

> Error: invalid_request Not authorized to request the scopes:
> [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login]
>
> Request Details
> oauth_token=4/TcuWLYAunz3MeOac23f0i4AZ6tQx

Is there any change at google side for oauth login process? any help regarding this issue is appreciated.

The scopes I am using

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
>
> https://docs.google.com/feeds/
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
>
> https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/

Comment: Those APIs and Oauth1 are deprecated. afaik they should still work, so I can't answer your specific problem, but migrating to the new APIs needs to be on your ToDo list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the plus.* scopes do not work (ie, are ignored) when accessing Google API's with an OAuth1 token. Thus, OAuth1 request for those scopes are currently not allowed. Replacing  plus.login by plus.me should solve your problem while still allowing you to obtain users' identifying information (see [scopes' documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#plus.me)).

Hope that helps!

Comment: documentation is helpful ,thnx for that ,but the scope "plus.me" is also not working..

Comment: Are you getting the same error? ie: "Error: invalid_request Not authorized to request the scopes: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me]"

Comment: oh i dun knw wat happened earlier but now this scope working,but am I restricted to google plus accounts only??...or it works for all..m lil confuse